# How to retrieve charset from a page of HTML that states

Tags: python, metadata

I open a website using:

```
resp = urlopen("http://...")
```

and for most sites when I call resp.info()['content-type'] I get the full string defined by  but for the page below I just get 'text/html'

```
<html ...>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
...
```

I don't know if the two meta tags are a reason (I doubt it) but why is "; charset.." not returned for either of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resp.info()['content-type'] is returning the information from the `Content-Type` header field not the page contents.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen): info() — return the meta-information of the page, such as headers, in the form of an mimetools.Message instance.

So it sounds like it could return the meta information from html but in this case is just returning the header information. If you really want the meta information from the page then try using an html parser to grab the contents of the page.

Comment: end of a long day - I missed the obvious! thanks for clearing the mist.